# Routing execute children component before parent using params

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem, I have  `ProductsService` which call data from the server and store in the `Array` and I have `ProductsComponent` component which is parent component and I have `ProductsListComponent` and `SingleProductComponent` which is children component. Flow is, In  `ProductsService` I have method:

```
 getCategoryFromServer() {
    this.dataStorageServiceServiceta.getCategory().subscribe((category: CategoryModel[]) => {
      this.categoryModule = category;
      this.cateogoryChange.next(this.categoryModule.slice())
    })
  }
```

And I have `categoryModule` array where data is stored.

In the `ProductsComponent` in the `ngOnInit` method I call the `getCategoryFromServer` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productsService.getCategoryFromServer();
  }
```

And template for `ProductsComponent` is:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <app-products-list></app-products-list>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row" >
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

I my screen is shown `app-products-list` component where I call data from the `serevice` you can see on the image how look like. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81ceo.png). When I click on the some items in this list, using  `[routerLink]="[products.name]"` my component `ProductListItemsComponent` is shown and look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM4QX.png).
Problem is when i refresh page and first is executed `SingleProductComponent` and after that `ProductsComponent` and my array is empty. Do you know how I can resolve this problem?

My routing module is :

```
const productsRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'productsList', component: ProductsComponent, children: [

        { path: ':category', component: ProductListItemsComponent },
        { path: ':category/:id', component: SingleProductComponent }


    ]
},

]
```

You can download from github https://github.com/milos2611/angular-shop.git github

Comment: Are u accessing the `categoryModule` array from both components?

Comment: Yes, i using `categoryModule` for both component. You can see in the github project.

Comment: @KinJong use `ngif` condition if API request data is get then child component is load.

Comment: Any example how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a get method from both components to access the array. Like in the product component,

```
get categoryModule(): Your_type[] {
   this.ProductsService.categoryModule;
}
```

Do this in both components and it will always get the values from product service.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <app-products-list></app-products-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row" >
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    </div>

  </div>
  {{categoryModule | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have method. 

 `this.subscription = this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.categoryName = params['category'];
          this.singleProducts = this.productsService.getListOfProduct(this.categoryName);

        })` But this execute before my parent component where I call data from server, and that is problem. I want first execute parent component `ProductsComponent` and after `ProductListItemsComponent`

Comment: is it necessary to order which component execute first? Because the `get` method will update as soon as the service data update.

Comment: Yes, exactly. that is my problem.